# HP 2600n Color Laser Printer in Debian 8.6

Tags: printing

this printer is quite old but the test page it prints still looks very nice, quality for black is excellent. so I would like to use it further.

I'm running Debian 8.6 and I tried 'hplip' from the distribution, I can add the printer with cups but then I get:

```
D [21/Oct/2016:13:34:29 +0200] [Job 38] Connected to printer.
D [21/Oct/2016:13:34:29 +0200] [Job 38] Connected to 192.168.55.156:9100...
D [21/Oct/2016:13:34:29 +0200] [Job 38] backendRunLoop(print_fd=0, device_fd=8, snmp_fd=7, addr=0x55a55ac99a08, use_bc=1, side_cb=0x55a559a55200)
D [21/Oct/2016:13:34:29 +0200] [Job 38] Read 16 bytes of print data...
D [21/Oct/2016:13:34:29 +0200] [Job 38] Wrote 16 bytes of print data...
D [21/Oct/2016:13:34:29 +0200] [Job 38] Waiting for printer to finish. 
D [21/Oct/2016:13:34:29 +0200] [Job 38] PID 15394 (/usr/lib/cups/backend/dnssd) exited with no errors.
D [21/Oct/2016:13:34:29 +0200] [Job 38] Processing page 3...
D [21/Oct/2016:13:34:29 +0200] [Job 38] Processing page 4...
D [21/Oct/2016:13:34:29 +0200] [Job 38] Rendering completed 
D [21/Oct/2016:13:34:29 +0200] [Job 38] PID 15392 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/gstoraster) exited with no errors.
D [21/Oct/2016:13:34:29 +0200] [Job 38] End of messages
D [21/Oct/2016:13:34:29 +0200] [Job 38] printer-state=3(idle)
D [21/Oct/2016:13:34:29 +0200] [Job 38] printer-state-message="Rendering completed"
D [21/Oct/2016:13:34:29 +0200] [Job 38] printer-state-reasons=hplip.plugin-error
E [21/Oct/2016:13:39:30 +0200] [Job 38] Stopping unresponsive job.
```

well...it just does not work. so I purged the 'hplip' solution and tried the 'hplib.run' from hp directly. I know that this will install files into the system that apt does not know about...but I'm fine with that. I want my hardware to work.

running the file shows:

```
MISSING DEPENDENCIES
--------------------
Following dependencies are not installed. 'HPLIP' will not work if all 
REQUIRED dependencies are not installed and some of the 'HPLIP' features will
not work if OPTIONAL dependencies are not installed.
Package-Name         Component            Required/Optional   
pyqt5-dbus           gui_qt5              REQUIRED            
libcrypto            network              REQUIRED            
libnetsnmp-devel     network              REQUIRED            
sane-devel           scan                 REQUIRED            
pyqt4-dbus           gui_qt4              REQUIRED            
cups-devel           base                 REQUIRED            
pyqt5                gui_qt5              REQUIRED            
libtool              base                 REQUIRED            
cups-image           base                 REQUIRED            
xsane                scan                 OPTIONAL            
dbus                 fax                  REQUIRED            
avahi-utils          network              OPTIONAL
```

and of course, the first package:

```
pyqt5-dbus
```

does not even exist in 8.6, the driver was apparently written for 8.5.
is there a way to solve this problem?

does 'hplip' really need this exact package installed or is the functionality implemented with different packages, and how are they called?

Comment: If I were you, I would stick to the Debian packages and try to figure out a solution with them. You can use a more recent version [from the backports](https://packages.debian.org/jessie-backports/hplip) if you want. I doubt that the upstream installer will solve your problem. Also, `hplip` is not the only system available to use your printer. You can try [Gutenprint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gutenprint) for example.

Comment: Have you seen? https://www.openprinting.org/printer/HP/HP-Color_LaserJet_2600n